# Mystery issue with embeded youtube video issue on IOS using Ionic/Cordova

Tags: html, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have previously been able to play embedded videos on my Android and iOS devices. After some time of updates, the video all of sudden stop working for iOS but still works for Android. This is weird and hard to debug for me since I know little of the iOS side. Could someone point out an obvious problem or suggestion? I even tried reverting the code to a time the YouTube videos did not work on the iOS and displays nothing.

Here is the code I am using

**HTML:**

```
<iframe ng-if="data.youtube" width="90%" height="315" src='{{trustSrc(data.youtube)}}' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false" id="informationVideoBorder"></iframe>
```

**JS:**

```
 $scope.trustSrc = function (src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
```

Any guru advice on tackling this?

Comment: See the browser's console logs for any errors and `src` of embedded `iframe`.

Comment: The console shows no errors. It looks fine in browser console (youtube video displays)

Comment: Can you provide one real value of `trustSrc(data.youtube)` ?

Comment: `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/CfFjwsA8PyU"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `iframe` try this iOS specific snippet:

**Controller:**

```
var video_embeded = 'CfFjwsA8PyU';
$scope.videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/v/'+video_embeded+'&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3";
```

**View**

```
<object>
  <param name="movie" value="{{videoUrl}}"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/'+video_embeded+'?suggestedQuality=medium&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: I am a little bit lost. What should I put in the html?

Comment: The View, and put the JS codes to the corresponding Controller.